# Message Bus and Message Based Architecture With Winforms/Desktop Application and Strategies/Policies for View/UI Logic

Tags: .net, architecture, message-queue, nservicebus, servicebus

Our company has been building out a product for year that is using a message-based architecture where modules register with the message bus and listen for messages that are dispatched to the bus and handled in their handler(s).

This is very similar if not exactly the same to what is provided from a product like NServiceBus, but we have some edge cases and needs that are not covered by products we have found, so we rolled our own. it has worked out very nicely thus far.

As we have had to implement some more complicated business logic recently, we have been noticing the code is starting to 'smell'. We are starting to see some of the following happen:

- Logic is making its way into some of the view(code behinds)
- We have a hard time with items in the view that need immediate feedback from a message that has been dispatched to the message queue.

An example of where this came up was when we needed to do a moderately complex wizard that conditionally determines the flow of the user through the wizard pages.

In order to try to keep the logic outside of the view, we dispatch messages and keep reference to the view originally in the message handler for that module, but this breaks down sometimes.

Is there anything out there that shows best practices or a common pattern for actual realistic examples of message bus systems, or do I have to make my own and just tolerate some of the more complex edge cases.

There doesn't seem to be much 'official' documentation on these types of system, just high level architecture overviews.

I imagine asking poeple who have done it before have discovered or stumbled upon a system that makes this easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you can look at.

One should never query over a service bus.  Your 'immediate feedback' is not really feasible.  You can implement a priority queue for scenarios where you need to deal with low latency requirements.  All queries should be handled by a synchronous query layer.

Having a UI respond to service bus messages should be fine but typically a UI's inbox should be transient and one should be able to purge it at system start up.

Your wizard scenario sounds quite a bit like an RPC call.  This may not be the best idea.  Your wizard path definition probably needs a re-look.  A service bus is not really designed to be an interactive affair :)

Answer (score 2):

Following on what @EbenRoux said in his answer, you probably wouldn't want to use a service bus for deciding flow in a wizard. That being said, the alternative is not to just stuff the code in the view.

You can keep the logic separate by packaging it in a different module/assembly and then referencing that from your view - or create a separate interface package for some looser-coupling. In any case, deploy that package in the same process as your view and do simple, synchronous request/response between them.

No service bus necessary for this.

There is no silver bullet.